# How get access to existed segue from storyboard by identifier in code?

Tags: swift, storyboard, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a segue with identifier (for example "SomeSegue") and need to get a access to this segue in code like this:

```
let mySegue = ...
```

How to do this?

> PageVC as containerView in VC, with segue(embed)

Comment: Cristik, in destination VC I have a prepare(for segue...) func. 
but in source VC this func doesn't work.

Comment: Cristik, I want to get access to source VC but this segue
...
let vc = segue.source as! MainViewController
...

like segue.destination

Answer (score 1):

It really seems that you are running into the XY problem (http://xyproblem.info).  There is not a good reason to get ahold of the Segue object itself.  You might wish to use the identifier to perform the Segue though.

If you need to manually perform a segue you can use the method `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` as documented here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssegueperforming/1409583-performsegue

Read the documentation in the "Discussion" section of that page carefully.